# Flex 4 reuse dialog box layout

Tags: user-interface, flex4, mxml

I've just create the first of dozens of pop-up dialogs in my Flex application and wondering what is the best way to reuse the layout so I don't have to duplicate it in every form.  I tried making a custom MXML component but when I inherited from it, I couldn't add child controls.  I'm not sure if CSS can handle it...or how.  Is the answer a skin?

Here is the contents of the dialog which is just a resizeable TitleWindow:

```
<components:layout>
    <s:BasicLayout />
</components:layout>

<!-- Content -->
<s:SkinnableContainer id="content" top="8" left="8" bottom="{buttonGroup.height + 16}" right="8" >
          ....content here....
</s:SkinnableContainer>

<!-- Buttons -->
<s:HGroup id="buttonGroup" left="8" bottom="8" right="8"> 
    ... buttons here...
</s:HGroup>
```

As you can see, it would really stink to have to duplicate that layout all over the place!

Comment: Very interesting question! You need some sort of a template component with two areas that act as some sort of a placeholders - placeholder for the content and a placeholder for the buttons. There doesn't seem to be an immediate solution with a skin or CSS. Hmmm... let me think!

Comment: Is there at least a way for me to get the margin "8" from CSS? Thus I can at least change the "padding" in one place.

Comment: There is! Check my answer below!

Answer (score 3):

Can I suggest you a bit different implementation:

```
<s:VGroup id="layoutContainer" styleName="layoutContainer">
    <!-- Content -->
    <s:SkinnableContainer id="content">
        ....content here....
    </s:SkinnableContainer>

    <!-- Buttons -->
    <s:HGroup id="buttonGroup"> 
        ... buttons here...
    </s:HGroup>
</s:VGroup>
```

And then in your CSS you should use some of the advanced selectors and you'll have a central place for all of the paddings:

```
form|SomeForm s:VGroup.layoutContainer,
form|SomeOtherForm s:VGroup.layoutContainer {
    top: 8;
    left: 8;
    right 8;
    bottom: 8;    
}
```

Check the [ZIP with the working sample](http://npacemo.com/sample-applications/TitleWindowSample.zip) I uploaded to my domain!

Comment: This would be perfect -- and in fact I started out using a VGroup because it was a good fit, but I ended up with a problem when resizing the pop-up dialog!  That other question is here...perhaps there is a better solution there that will allow me to go back to using a VGRoup:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436731/flex-4-vertical-layout-problem-on-titlewindow

Comment: @HDave I've added an answer to the new question. Let me know if that worked!

Comment: that worked, but the solution here...is not working for me at the moment, though I don't know why.  The CSS settings are ignored.  I fixed the padding names which were incorrect, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: With the advanced CSS selectors is a bit of a trial and error until you get the right selector specified. When you write the selector are you using the base class or the specific sub-class? Is the layoutContainer inside of a skin or you use only one monolithic MXML?

Comment: I have verified that your selector works by changing the color, but the values for padding are being ignored.  Looking at the reference manual for VGroup I don't see the paddings listed in the styles.  Check here:  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/VGroup.html#styleSummary

Comment: You're absolutely right - these are just regular properties. The thing that Flash Builder hints you those doesn't mean these are styles applicable to VGroup. Well, the styles that are working are top, bottom, left, right... Somewhat unsatisfying, right?

Comment: Yes, but your help on my other question was huge because it allowed me to go back to a VerticalLayout which mean I could put the paddings in a superclass commmon to all the dialogs.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: If you need to set up "content" part and "buttons" part at runtime and still be able to use your custom component in MXML... well, I doubt it's possible. If you abandon MXML you have to create some configurational object for your component and pass it to the constructor, and also you need overriden method createChildren in your custom component.
If "buttons" part is static - read below text.

You could try to create a custom SkinnableComponent and a skin class for this component where you will place your layout.
1) Extend from the SkinnableComponent, like this

```
public class CustomSkinnable extend SkinnableComponent
{
    [SkinPart[required="true"])
    public var submitButton:Button;
    //the same with cancel button for example
    //override partAdd function to add event listeners to your buttons if you wish
    //and other stuff folowing the manual
}
```

2) Create skin for you component (Flash Builder very usefull) [for example]

```
<s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
        width="{backgroundRect.width}" height="{backgroundRect.height}">
    <!-- host component -->
    <fx:Metadata>
        [HostComponent("components.CustomSkinnable")]
    </fx:Metadata>

    <!-- SkinParts
    name=submitButton, type=spark.components.Button, required=true
    ...
    -->

    <s:Rect id="backgroundRect"
            x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:stroke>
            <s:SolidColorStroke color="#000000"/>
        </s:stroke>
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="#444444"/>
        </s:fill>        
    </s:Rect>          

    <s:Group>
        <!-- Content -->
        <s:SkinnableContainer id="contentGroup" top="8" left="8" bottom="{buttonGroup.height + 16}" right="8" >
          ....content here....
        </s:SkinnableContainer>

        <!-- Buttons -->
        <s:HGroup id="buttonGroup" left="8" bottom="8" right="8"> 
          <s:Button id="submitButton" label="Submit"/>
          ... additional buttons here...
        </s:HGroup> 
    </s:Group>    
</s:Skin>
```

Notice that id="contentGroup" instead of id="content" is not just like that, contentGroup is a static part of every skin where child elements are placed.